# Does std::copy handle overlapping ranges?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, copy

When copying data from one range to another, you have to be careful if there's partial overlap between the source and destination ranges.  If the beginning of the destination range overlaps the tail of the source range, a plain sequential copy will garble the data.  The C run-time library has `memmove` in addition to `memcpy` to handle such overlap problems.

I assume `std::copy` works like `memcpy`, in that it doesn't pay any regard to overlap between the source and destination regions.  If you try to shift objects "down" in a `std::vector` with `std::copy`, you'll corrupt the data.  Is there an STL algorithm analogue of `memmove` to handle situations like this?  Or should I roll my own with reverse iterators?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It doesn't handle overlapping ranges if the *beginning* of the output range overlaps with the input range.

Fortunately, you can use **[`std::copy_backward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward)** instead (which requires that you don't overlap the *end* of the output range with the input range).

Comment: `std::copy_backward` would be useful in trying to implement and analogue of `memmove`.  I want to take the checking for overlap burden off of the caller.

Answer (score 9):

Preconditions  for [`std::copy`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/copy.html), prohibits an overlap:

> - Prototype
>
>   ```
>   template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
>   OutputIterator copy(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
>                       OutputIterator result);
>   ```
> - Preconditions
>
>   - `[first, last)` is a valid range.
>   - result is not an iterator within the range `[first, last)`.
>   - There is enough space to hold all of the elements being copied. More
>       formally, the requirement is that
>       `[result, result + (last - first))` is a
>       valid range. [[1]](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/copy.html)

Comment: That answers the question in the title.  The remaining question is whether there's an analogue of `memmove` or if I have to roll my own.

Comment: That only prohibits an overlap with the start of the destination range. As John says, an overlap with the middle or end is allowed, and `std::copy_backward` allows an overlap with the start (but not the end).

Answer (score 3):

**C++17 standard draft**

The [C++17 n4659 standard draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4659.pdf) says:

28.6.1 "Copy":

> ```
> template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
> OutputIterator copy(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
>                     OutputIterator result);
> ```
>
> 1 Requires: result shall not be in the range [first, last).
>
> 2 Effects: Copies elements in the range [first, last) into the range [result, result + (last -
>   first)) starting from first and proceeding to last.

and:

> ```
> template<class BidirectionalIterator1, class BidirectionalIterator2>
> BidirectionalIterator2
> copy_backward(
>     BidirectionalIterator1 first,
>     BidirectionalIterator1 last,
>     BidirectionalIterator2 result);
> ```
>
> 17 Requires: result shall not be in the range (first, last].
>
> 18 Effects: Copies elements in the range [first, last) into the range [result - (last-first),
>   result) starting from last - 1 and proceeding to first. (263) For each positive integer n <= (last -
>   first), performs *(result - n) = *(last - n).

The note then explains when to use `copy_backward`:

> 263) copy_backward should be used instead of copy when last is in the range [result - (last - first), result)

Therefore, there is no requirement of no overlap for those functions, and [unlike for `memcpy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415910/memcpy-vs-memmove/53486461#53486461), the behavior of overlaps is clearly defined in the `Effects` sections.

You just choose between them because you usually want `std::copy` for copying left and `std::copy_backward` for copying right.

C++ also has a ranged version of `std::move` in `<algorithm>` which moves instead of copying.

Comment: The gist of the question was whether there's an analog of `std::memmove` that takes the responsibility of checking for overlap off of the caller.  The answer is no.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy thanks for feedback. My answer also implies that, but with standard quote :-)

Comment: This does not take care of the occation where std::copy is optimized with parallel method such as omp, is this ? Since in parallel senario there will still be overlap even if we copy from backward.

Comment: @coincheung no idea, but it would be insane to break C++ standard requirements on a function with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the most straight forward way would be to  create a temporary vector of the range you want to copy:

```
std::vector copiedRange( srcVecIterBegin, srcVecIterEnd);
std::copy( copiedRange.begin(), copiedRange.end(), srcVecIterCopyLocIter);
```

You can wrap this in a templated function that should be ably to do an overlapped using any container/iterator type.

Comment: Yeah, but that might lead to a lot more copying than necessary.  I'd rather right a function that tests for overlap and then uses the right copy technique to do it in place.