# memcpy() vs memmove()

Tags: c, memcpy, memmove

I am trying to understand the difference between [`memcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) and [`memmove()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove), and I have read the text that `memcpy()` doesn't take care of the overlapping source and destination whereas `memmove()` does.

However, when I execute these two functions on overlapping memory blocks, they both give the same result. For instance, take the following MSDN example on the `memmove()` help page:-

Is there a better example to understand the drawbacks of `memcpy` and how `memmove` solves it?

```
// crt_memcpy.c
// Illustrate overlapping copy: memmove always handles it correctly; memcpy may handle
// it correctly.

#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char str1[7] = "aabbcc";

int main( void )
{
    printf( "The string: %s\n", str1 );
    memcpy( str1 + 2, str1, 4 );
    printf( "New string: %s\n", str1 );

    strcpy_s( str1, sizeof(str1), "aabbcc" );   // reset string

    printf( "The string: %s\n", str1 );
    memmove( str1 + 2, str1, 4 );
    printf( "New string: %s\n", str1 );
}
```

#### Output:

```
memcpy():
The string: aabbcc
New string: aaaabb

memmove():
The string: aabbcc
New string: aaaabb
```

Comment: The Microsoft CRT has had a safe memcpy() for quite a while.

Comment: I don't think "safe" is the right word for it. A safe `memcpy` would `assert` that the regions don't overlap rather than intentionally covering up bugs in your code.

Comment: Depends on whether you mean "safe for the developer" or "safe for the end-user". I would argue that doing as told, even if it isn't standards-compliant is the safer choice for the end-user.

Comment: since glibc 2.19 - not work 
`The string: aabbcc
New string: aaaaaa
The string: aabbcc
New string: aaaabb`

Comment: You can also see [here](http://www.tedunangst.com/flak/post/memcpy-vs-memmove).

Comment: Microsoft's "safe" memcpy() is a fallback to memmove() https://twitter.com/MalwareMinigun/status/737801492808142848

Comment: A good example with pictures on the subject of "What can go wrong with `memcpy(...)` can be found here: [memcpy vs memmove](http://www.equestionanswers.com/c/memcpy-vs-memmove.php).

Answer (score 159, accepted):

I'm not entirely surprised that your example exhibits no strange behaviour. Try copying `str1` to `str1+2` instead and see what happens then. (May not actually make a difference, depends on compiler/libraries.)

In general, memcpy is implemented in a simple (but fast) manner. Simplistically, it just loops over the data (in order), copying from one location to the other. This can result in the source being overwritten while it's being read.

Memmove does more work to ensure it handles the overlap correctly.

EDIT:

(Unfortunately, I can't find decent examples, but these will do). Contrast the [memcpy](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/memcpy) and [memmove](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/memmove) implementations shown here. memcpy just loops, while memmove performs a test to determine which direction to loop in to avoid corrupting the data. These implementations are rather simple. Most high-performance implementations are more complicated (involving copying word-size blocks at a time rather than bytes).

Comment: +1 Also, in the following implementation, `memmove` calls `memcpy` in one branch after testing the pointers: http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs350/common/os161-src-html/memmove_8c-source.html

Comment: That sounds great. Seems like Visual Studio implements a "safe" memcpy (along with gcc 4.1.1, I tested on RHEL 5 as well). Writing the versions of these functions from clc-wiki.net gives a clear picture. Thanks.

Comment: memcpy doesn't take care of the overlapping-issue, but memmove does. Then why not eliminate memcpy from the lib?

Comment: @Alcott: Because `memcpy` can be faster.

Comment: Fixed/webarchive link from Pascal Cuoq above: https://web.archive.org/web/20130722203254/http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs350/common/os161-src-html/memmove_8c-source.html

Answer (score 135):

The memory in `memcpy` **cannot** overlap or you risk undefined behaviour, while the memory in `memmove` can overlap.

```
char a[16];
char b[16];

memcpy(a,b,16);           // Valid.
memmove(a,b,16);          // Also valid, but slower than memcpy.
memcpy(&a[0], &a[1],10);  // Not valid since it overlaps.
memmove(&a[0], &a[1],10); // Valid.
```

Some implementations of `memcpy` might still work for overlapping inputs, but you cannot count on that behaviour. However, `memmove` must allow for overlapping inputs.

Comment: it really helped me thaks! +1 for your info

Answer (score 40):

Just because `memcpy` doesn't have to deal with overlapping regions, doesn't mean it doesn't deal with them correctly. The call with overlapping regions produces undefined behavior. Undefined behavior can work entirely as you expect on one platform; that doesn't mean it's correct or valid.

Comment: In particular, depending on the platform, it's possible that `memcpy` is implemented exactly the same way as `memmove`. That is, whoever wrote the compiler didn't bother writing a unique `memcpy` function.

Answer (score 20):

Both memcpy and memove do similar things.

But to sight out one difference:

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char str1[7] = "abcdef";

int main()
{

   printf( "The string: %s\n", str1 );
   memcpy( (str1+6), str1, 10 );
   printf( "New string: %s\n", str1 );

   strcpy_s( str1, sizeof(str1), "aabbcc" );   // reset string


   printf("\nstr1: %s\n", str1);
   printf( "The string: %s\n", str1 );
   memmove( (str1+6), str1, 10 );
   printf( "New string: %s\n", str1 );

}
```

gives:

```
The string: abcdef
New string: abcdefabcdefabcd
The string: abcdef
New string: abcdefabcdef
```

Comment: IMHO, this example program has some flaws, since the str1 buffer is accessed out of bounds (10 bytes to copy, buffer is 7 bytes in size). The out of bounds error results in undefined behavior. The differences in the shown results of the memcpy()/memmove() calls are implementation specific. And the example output doesn't exactly match the program above... Also, strcpy_s() is not part of standard C AFAIK (MS specific, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723946/why-does-strcpy-s-not-exist-anywhere-on-my-system/36724095#36724095) - Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 14):

Your demo didn't expose memcpy drawbacks because of "bad" compiler, it does you a favor in Debug version. A release version, however, gives you the same output, but because of optimization.

```
    memcpy(str1 + 2, str1, 4);
00241013  mov         eax,dword ptr [str1 (243018h)]  // load 4 bytes from source string
    printf("New string: %s\n", str1);
00241018  push        offset str1 (243018h) 
0024101D  push        offset string "New string: %s\n" (242104h) 
00241022  mov         dword ptr [str1+2 (24301Ah)],eax  // put 4 bytes to destination
00241027  call        esi
```

The register `%eax` here plays as a temporary storage, which "elegantly" fixes overlap issue.

The drawback emerges when copying 6 bytes, well, at least part of it.

```
char str1[9] = "aabbccdd";

int main( void )
{
    printf("The string: %s\n", str1);
    memcpy(str1 + 2, str1, 6);
    printf("New string: %s\n", str1);

    strcpy_s(str1, sizeof(str1), "aabbccdd");   // reset string

    printf("The string: %s\n", str1);
    memmove(str1 + 2, str1, 6);
    printf("New string: %s\n", str1);
}
```

Output:

```
The string: aabbccdd
New string: aaaabbbb
The string: aabbccdd
New string: aaaabbcc
```

Looks weird, it's caused by optimization, too.

```
    memcpy(str1 + 2, str1, 6);
00341013  mov         eax,dword ptr [str1 (343018h)] 
00341018  mov         dword ptr [str1+2 (34301Ah)],eax // put 4 bytes to destination, earlier than the above example
0034101D  mov         cx,word ptr [str1+4 (34301Ch)]  // HA, new register! Holding a word, which is exactly the left 2 bytes (after 4 bytes loaded to %eax)
    printf("New string: %s\n", str1);
00341024  push        offset str1 (343018h) 
00341029  push        offset string "New string: %s\n" (342104h) 
0034102E  mov         word ptr [str1+6 (34301Eh)],cx  // Again, pulling the stored word back from the new register
00341035  call        esi
```

This is why I always choose `memmove` when trying to copy 2 overlapped memory blocks.

Answer (score 6):

**C11 standard draft**

The [C11 N1570 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says:

7.24.2.1 "The memcpy function":

> 2 The memcpy function copies n characters from the object pointed to by s2 into the
>   object pointed to by s1. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior
>   is undefined.

7.24.2.2 "The memmove function":

> 2
>   The memmove function copies n characters from the object pointed to by s2 into the
>   object pointed to by s1. Copying takes place as if the n characters from the object
>   pointed to by s2 are first copied into a temporary array of n characters that does not
>   overlap the objects pointed to by s1 and s2, and then the n characters from the
>   temporary array are copied into the object pointed to by s1

Therefore, any overlap on `memcpy` leads to undefined behavior, and anything can happen: bad, nothing or even good. Good is rare though :-)

`memmove` however clearly says that everything happens as if an intermediate buffer is used, so clearly overlaps are OK.

C++ `std::copy` is more forgiving however, and allows overlaps: [Does std::copy handle overlapping ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952972/does-stdcopy-handle-overlapping-ranges/53487672#53487672)

Comment: `memmove` use an extra temporary array of n, so does it use extra memory? But how can it if we haven't given it access to any memory. (It's using 2x the memory).

Comment: @clmno it allocates on stack or malloc like any other function I'd expect :-)

Comment: I'd asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55370165), got a good answer too. Thank you. Saw your hackernews [post](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19428700) that went viral (the x86 one) :)

Answer (score 4):

The difference between `memcpy` and `memmove` is that

1. in `memmove`, the source memory of specified size is copied into buffer and then moved     to destination. So if the memory is overlapping, there are no side effects.
2. in case of `memcpy()`, there is no extra buffer taken for source memory. The copying     is done directly on the memory so that when there is memory overlap, we get unexpected results.

These can be observed by the following code:

```
//include string.h, stdio.h, stdlib.h
int main(){
  char a[]="hare rama hare rama";

  char b[]="hare rama hare rama";

  memmove(a+5,a,20);
  puts(a);

  memcpy(b+5,b,20);
  puts(b);
}
```

Output is:

```
hare hare rama hare rama
hare hare hare hare hare hare rama hare rama
```

Comment: -1 - there is no requirement for memmove to actually copy data into a separate buffer

Comment: this example does not help in understanding the concept .... as most of the compilers will give the same out as mem move output

Comment: @jjwchoy Conceptually it does. The buffer would usually be optimized out

Comment: The same result, on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

As already pointed out in other answers, `memmove` is more sophisticated than `memcpy` such that it accounts for memory overlaps. The result of memmove is defined as if the `src` was copied into a buffer and then buffer copied into `dst`. This does NOT mean that the actual implementation uses any buffer, but probably does some pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

compiler could optimize memcpy, for example:

```
int x;
memcpy(&x, some_pointer, sizeof(int));
```

This memcpy may be optimized as: `x = *(int*)some_pointer;`

Comment: Such an optimization is permissible only on architectures which allow unaligned `int` accesses. On some architectures (e.g. Cortex-M0), attempting to fetch a 32-bit `int` from an address which is not a multiple of four will cause a crash (but `memcpy` would work).  If one will either be using a CPU which allows unaligned access or using a compiler with a keyword that directs the compiler to assemble integers out of separately-fetched bytes when necessary, one could do something like `#define UNALIGNED __unaligned` and then `x=*(int UNALIGNED*)some_pointer;

Comment: Some processors do not allow unaligned int access crash `char x = "12345"; int *i; i = *(int *)(x + 1);` But some do, because they fix up the copy during the fault. I worked on a system like this, and it took a bit of time to understand why performance was so poor.

Comment: `*(int *)some_pointer` is a strict aliasing violation, but you probably mean that the compiler would output assembly which copies an int

Answer (score 1):

The code given in the links http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/memcpy for memcpy seems to confuse me a bit, as it does not give the same output when I implemented it using the below example.

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char str1[11] = "abcdefghij";

void *memcpyCustom(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    char *dp = (char *)dest;
    const char *sp = (char *)src;
    while (n--)
        *dp++ = *sp++;
    return dest;
}

void *memmoveCustom(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    unsigned char *pd = (unsigned char *)dest;
    const unsigned char *ps = (unsigned char *)src;
    if ( ps < pd )
        for (pd += n, ps += n; n--;)
            *--pd = *--ps;
    else
        while(n--)
            *pd++ = *ps++;
    return dest;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf( "The string: %s\n", str1 );
    memcpy( str1 + 1, str1, 9 );
    printf( "Actual memcpy output: %s\n", str1 );

    strcpy_s( str1, sizeof(str1), "abcdefghij" );   // reset string

    memcpyCustom( str1 + 1, str1, 9 );
    printf( "Implemented memcpy output: %s\n", str1 );

    strcpy_s( str1, sizeof(str1), "abcdefghij" );   // reset string

    memmoveCustom( str1 + 1, str1, 9 );
    printf( "Implemented memmove output: %s\n", str1 );
    getchar();
}
```

Output :

```
The string: abcdefghij
Actual memcpy output: aabcdefghi
Implemented memcpy output: aaaaaaaaaa
Implemented memmove output: aabcdefghi
```

But you can now understand why [memmove](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/memmove) will take care of overlapping issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example I wrote, please refer to it. The memory copy overwriting problem will only occur when the area where dst is located is behind the src area.

```c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])

#define PRINT_ARRAY(arr, size, format)      \
    do {                                    \
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) { \
            printf(format, arr[i]);         \
        }                                   \
        printf("\n");                       \
    } while (0)

int test_memcpy_memmove(void)
{
    /* T1 src and dst memory do not overlap at all */
    char s1[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
    char s2[] = {'1', '2', '3', '\0'};

    printf("T1--------------------------:\n");
    printf("before s1 and s2:\n");
    PRINT_ARRAY(s1, ARRAY_SIZE(s1), "%c");
    PRINT_ARRAY(s2, ARRAY_SIZE(s1), "%c");
    printf("after use memcpy s2:\n");
    memcpy(s2, s1, 3);
    PRINT_ARRAY(s2, ARRAY_SIZE(s1), "%c");

    /* T2 src and dst memory overlap, and the area where dst is located is in front of the src area */
    printf("T2--------------------------:\n");
    char a[10] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'};
    char b[10] = {0};
    memcpy(b, a, sizeof(char) * 10);
    printf("before a and b:\n");
    PRINT_ARRAY(a, ARRAY_SIZE(a), "%c");
    PRINT_ARRAY(b, ARRAY_SIZE(b), "%c");

    printf("after use memcpy a:\n");
    memcpy(&a[0], &a[2], 3);
    PRINT_ARRAY(a, ARRAY_SIZE(a), "%c"); // cdedef

    printf("after use memmove b:\n");
    memmove(&b[0], &b[2], 3);
    PRINT_ARRAY(a, ARRAY_SIZE(a), "%c"); // cdedef

    /* T3 !!! The memory of src and dst overlap, and the area of dst is behind the src area. */
    printf("T3--------------------------:\n");
    char c[10] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'};
    char d[10] = {0};
    memcpy(d, c, sizeof(char) * 10);
    printf("before c and d:\n");
    PRINT_ARRAY(c, ARRAY_SIZE(c), "%c");
    PRINT_ARRAY(d, ARRAY_SIZE(d), "%c");

    printf("after use memcpy c:\n");
    memcpy(&c[2], &c[0], 3);
    PRINT_ARRAY(c, ARRAY_SIZE(c),
                "%c"); // ababaf >>uses memcpy to overwrite the original characters expected to be copied

    printf("after use memmove d:\n");
    memmove(&d[2], &d[0], 3);
    PRINT_ARRAY(d, ARRAY_SIZE(d),
                "%c"); // ababcf >>uses memmove and does not overwrite the characters to be copied
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

I have tried to run same program using eclipse and it shows clear difference between `memcpy` and `memmove`. `memcpy()` doesn't care about overlapping of memory location which results in corruption of data, while `memmove()` will copy data to temporary variable first and then copy into actual memory location.

While trying to copy data from location `str1` to `str1+2`, output of `memcpy` is "`aaaaaa`". The question would be how?
`memcpy()` will copy one byte at a time from left to right. As shown in your program "`aabbcc`" then 
all copying will take place as below,

1. `aabbcc -> aaabcc`
2. `aaabcc -> aaaacc`
3. `aaaacc -> aaaaac`
4. `aaaaac -> aaaaaa`

`memmove()` will copy data to temporary variable first and then copy to actual memory location.

1. `aabbcc(actual) -> aabbcc(temp)`
2. `aabbcc(temp) -> aaabcc(act)`
3. `aabbcc(temp) -> aaaacc(act)`
4. `aabbcc(temp) -> aaaabc(act)`
5. `aabbcc(temp) -> aaaabb(act)`

Output is

`memcpy`  : `aaaaaa`

`memmove` : `aaaabb`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  There are various issues to address.  First and foremost, you added an answer to a question with multiple answers from 18 months or so ago.  To warrant the addition, you would need to provide startling new information.  Second, you specify Eclipse, but Eclipse is an IDE that uses a C compiler, but you don't identify the platform where your code is running or the C compiler Eclipse is using. I'd be interested to know how you ascertain that `memmove()` copies to an intermediate location. It should just copy in reverse when necessary.

Comment: Thanks. About the compiler, so i am using gcc compiler on linux.
There is a man page in linux for the memove which clearly specifies that memove will copy data in temporary variable to avoid overlapping of data.
Here is the link of that man page http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove

Comment: It actually says "as if", which does not mean that it is what actually happens. Granted it _could_ actually do it that way (though there'd be questions about where it gets the spare memory from), but I would be more than a little surprised if that was what it actually does. If the source address is greater than the target address, it is sufficient to copy from the start to the end (forwards copy); if the source address is less than the target address, it is sufficient to copy from the end to the start (backwards copy). No auxilliary memory is needed or used.

Comment: try to explain your answer with actual data in code, that would be more helpful.