# Does memmove actually "move" a chunk of memory and leave behind zeros at the source?

Tags: c, memcpy, memmove

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [memcpy vs memmove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415910/memcpy-vs-memmove)

Does [memmove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/) actually "move" a chunk of memory? If so, does it leave the memory with zeros? Or, is it just like [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/?kw=memcpy)? I am looking at the man page, and I do not believe my assumption is correct. If I want to move a chunk of memory using memmove, would I have to manually zero out the chunk of memory where I did the move?

Answer (score 5):

`memmove` has nothing to do with clearing the old memory, and in fact in the only situations where you would want to use `memmove`, clearing the old memory would destroy the data you just copied! That's because `memmove` is only useful when you expect the source and destination ranges to overlap.

Usually, if you find yourself needing `memmove`, it's indicative that you have a major fundamental inefficiency in your design. For instance, often new C programmers will try to use `memmove` to remove the first few characters of a string (e.g. `memmove(s, &s[1], len)`) rather than just using `s+1` or `&s[1]` to address the tail of the string. Algorithms containing `memmove` rarely perform better than O(n^2).

Answer (score 4):

Not quite:

The main difference between `memmove` and `memcpy` is that `memmove` can be used to relocate a piece of memory to somewhere that overlaps the memory block that you're trying to move. And therefore the original pointer will no longer be valid.

With `memcpy`, on the other hand, the two areas cannot overlap.

`memmove` doesn't zero the original memory block though. If you want to do that, you'll have to explicitly do it yourself with [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/?kw=memset). As a rule, C routines don't waste cycles doing things that may not be necessary, such as zeroing memory. Compare with `malloc`, which likewise does not zero the memory block.

Comment: But be careful with generalizing... `calloc()` does zero memory. (Note: this isn't a knock on tylerl's answer, just a warning that C has many idiosyncrasies. C++ does, too).