# Memmove making one spot garbage?

Tags: c++

I'm using `memmove` to shift `std::string` elements to the right by one spot. The first spot of the destination is the only spot that gets messed up and filled with garbage. I am using `memmove` instead of `strcpy` because I am using it in a class that requires templates. It works fine when I have an array of ints though. Any idea on how to fix this for strings?

```
/**
 * @brief Shifts elements in the array to the right
 * @param newItem The insert position.
 */
template<class T>
void DynamicArray<T>::shiftElementsRight(uint newItem) {
    uint diff = _size - newItem;
    memmove(&(_array[newItem + 1]),
            &(_array[newItem]), sizeof(_array[0]) * diff);
}
```

My Main

```
int main() {
    DynamicArray<string> array(1);

    string val1 = "val1";
    array.add(val1);
    string val2 = "val2";
    array.add(val2);
    // ... more additions ...
```

The last output:

```
Sizeof: 8
Value is: val1
Value is: val11val3, val21
                            ����[val1, val2A����[val1, val2, val31val4, Aq�����[val1, val2, val3 val4, val5Q`r�#����[val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val61val5, 1val6, Q"����[val1, val2, val3, al4, a
8s��p�hp��p�hq�(r�Xr�؄KC�؄KC�؄KC�1val7, a:����[val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, qF����[val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither `memcpy` nor `memmove` are possible when your array contains `std::string` objects. The reason is that both tamper with the objects' internals when they shouldn't (the integrity of a C++ object is ensured by its constructor / assignment operator / destructor / member functions, you **must not** modify its bytes manually unless you know exactly what you do).

As already suggested, use a method that takes constructors, assignment operators and destructors into account (`std::copy_backward` for example) or better yet, get rid of those legacy C arrays and use proper C++ containers like `vector` and use the container's functions to insert/remove items.

In other words, as soon as you start using C++ objects then you have to begin writing C++, not "C with classes" any more.

Answer (score 2):

From [memcpy description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/):

> To avoid overflows, the size of the arrays pointed by both the
>   destination and source parameters, shall be at least num bytes, and
>   should not overlap (for overlapping memory blocks, memmove is a safer
>   approach).

Use [memmove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/), in other words.

Answer (score 1):

Like most people here say you can use [`memmove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove) instead of [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) because it can handle overlapping ranges.

However, the C++ solution would be to use [`copy_backward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward), which does explicitly what you asked for and will behind the screens choose the fastest copy method for you. That would look something like this:

```
std::copy_backward(std::begin(_array)+newItem, std::end(_array)-1, std::end(array));
```

This means you will copy backwards from the previous-to-last element to position newItem and will insert that starting from the back. This can obviously handle the overlap this requires. It might be that behind the screens memmove or other platform-specific memory copies are used.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SYNOPSIS
        #include <string.h>

        void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);

 DESCRIPTION
        The  memcpy()  function  copies  n bytes from memory area src to memory
        area dest.  The memory areas must not overlap.  Use memmove(3)  if  the
        memory areas do overlap.
```

Your memory areas must not overlap, otherwise `memcpy`'s behavior is not defined.  You should use `memmove` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may not use `memcpy` for overlapping ranges, as is stated in the library documentation:

> 7.21.2 Copying functions
>
> 7.21.2.1 The memcpy function
>
> ...
>
> 2 The memcpy function copies n characters from the object pointed to by s2 into the object pointed to by s1. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, **the behavior is undefined**.
>
> 7.21.2.2 The memmove function
>
> ...
>
> 2 The memmove function copies n characters from the object pointed to by s2 into the
>   object pointed to by s1. Copying takes place as if the n characters from the object
>   pointed to by s2 are first copied into a temporary array of n characters that does not
>   overlap the objects pointed to by s1 and s2, and then the n characters from the
>   temporary array are copied into the object pointed to by s1.

For POD or trivially initialized types, you can either use `memmove` (as suggested above) or `std::copy_backward` (so long as the last destination element is not within the source range)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415910/memcpy-vs-memmove) has more discussion of the memcpy-vs-memmove part.

For non-trivial types such as `std::string`, you can't use either `memcpy` *or* `memmove`, but *must* use `std::copy` or `std::copy_backward`.