# Order of execution for `::memcpy`

Tags: c++, memcpy

I'm writing a class member function to remove a row from a (m x n) matrix. The memory model for the matrix (from a standard linear algebra library) is guaranteed to be a contiguous block such that the (i, j)th element maps to the (i * n + j)th element of that memory block.

I'd like to use `::memcpy` for clarity and performance reasons. (The alternative ways using `for` loops are cumbersome.)  But I need some reassurance.

In general, the destination location **overlaps** the source location since, if I'm deleting row *r*, I'd use (dropping any casts for clarity),

```
::memcpy(r * n, (r + 1) * n, bigger than n in general)
```

If `::memcpy` is guaranteed to copy from the start of the block, then this will be fine. But, does the standard guarantee this? I can't see why it would and suspect the behaviour of such code is *undefined*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415910/memcpy-vs-memmove

Comment: On modern systems, a `for` loop will frequently perform as well or better than `memcpy`. Some compilers can take advantage of type and alignment information when you invoke through a `for` loop but not when you call `memcpy`. (And *way* better than `memmove` since the direction is more likely to be determined at compile time rather than at run time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `memmove` instead of `memcpy`. The overlapping behaviour for `memmove` is defined.

User [thang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1779316/thang) pointed out in a comment, there is a [related article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415910/memcpy-vs-memmove) which dicusses the difference between `memcpy` and `memmove`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `std::copy` or `std::copy_backwards`?