# C++ Help converting string to uint8_t

Tags: c++, string, int, byte

I am currently working with an embedded system that will be communicating to various devices using serial communication. I use a `uint8_t` variable for the buffers sent and received by the embedded board. I need to modify these values (preferably using `string`) and then convert them back to `uint8_t` after they have been modified. I have created a simple test code for messing around with `uint8_t`'s and `strings`. The problem I am having is the output from `cout` only displays "GREE" (regardless of the value of `myString`, it is always only 4 characters for some reason). I have tried a few ways to accomplish this task and would really appreciate some help. Maybe I'm missing something that's easy to fix? I've been on the computer for almost 8 hours.

```
string myString = "GREETINGS";
const uint8_t *p = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(myString.c_str());
myString.assign(p, p + sizeof(p));
cout << myString << endl;
```

OUTPUT IS: GREE

Comment: `p` is a pointer.  `sizeof(p)` is going to be the size of a pointer.  If your string holds arbitrary bytes, that pointer alone is not going to know how many bytes were held in the string.

Comment: I've definitely been looking at the computer too long to miss something like that haha! Thanks Drew, just fixed it. Pays to have fresh eyes take a peak once in a while.

Comment: [Some say](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142011/can-you-assign-a-substring-of-a-stdstring-to-itself) that string self-`.assign` ment is dodgy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As *@Drew Dormann* points out (pun intended): `p` is a pointer with size `sizeof(p)`. The size of a pointer is a system specification, which on your system seems to be 4 bytes. A `char` is 1 byte, so you are seeing 4 `chars`.

So, we must change the size:

```
string myString = "GREETINGS";

const uint8_t *p = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(myString.c_str());

myString.assign(p, p + myString.size());

cout << myString << endl;
```

Comment: Uhm... `sizeof(myString)`? Seriously? Do you want to reconsider? Need more time?

Comment: Did you mean `myString.size()`?

Comment: When you say *"or any pointer"* you are ignoring member function pointers. Member function pointers are generally larger than other pointers. And pointers are *"traditionally"* 8 bytes. 64-bit OS' have been around for well over a decade now...

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the input, and I hope Spencer resolved his problem!

Comment: I am confused by the amount of down votes. Please leave a comment

Comment: I got it figured out! I guess I had been staring at the computer too long to notice such a simple mistake!

Answer (score 2):

> regardless of the value of myString, it is always only 4 characters for some reason

Check the value of `sizeof(p)`. Print it using `cout`. It is the size of a pointer. It is `4` on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

p is the pointer. 
When you use sizeof() for pointers you will get 4 or 8. It depends on the architecture you use. For x86 - 4, x64 - 8.

`myString.assign(p, p + sizeof(p));// assign first 4 symbols to the string`