# Why does strcpy_s not exist anywhere on my system?

Tags: c++, header, debian, clang

I'm using `clang` on a Debian 8 system. I have the standard C++ headers. And yet, there is no header defining `strcpy_s`. Why is this?

```
# grep -iRHI 'strcpy_s' /usr 2>/dev/null
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string2.h:                ? __strcpy_small (dest, __strcpy_args (src),             \
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string2.h:__STRING_INLINE char *__strcpy_small (char *, __uint16_t, __uint16_t,
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string2.h:__strcpy_small (char *__dest,
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string2.h:__STRING_INLINE char *__strcpy_small (char *, __STRING2_COPY_ARR2,
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string2.h:__strcpy_small (char *__dest,
/usr/src/broadcom-sta-6.30.223.248/src/include/bcmutils.h:#define bcm_strcpy_s(dst, noOfElements, src)            strcpy((dst), (src))
```

Comment: Did you come by a solution in the meantime?

Comment: Not that I recall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, these don't exist because they don't exist. And I can find and install them by finding and installing them; or, alternatively, by coding them myself. Apparently this is a helpful solution, so let the upvotes begin.

Comment: I upvoted. Slap this into anything that needs strcpy_s `template<typename C>inline int strcpy_s(C*d,unsigned long dmax,const C*s){if(dmax<=1||!d){if(!d||!dmax)return 22;*d=C(0);return 0;}for(C*de=d+dmax-1;(d!=de||(*d=C(0)))&&(*d=*s);++d,++s);return 0;}`

Comment: Thank you. But I'm still missing all the other functions :(

Answer (score 6):

> Why does strcpy_s not exist anywhere on my system?

`strcpy_s` is not provided by the C++ standard library.

`strcpy_s` is however, specified by the C standard standard since C11. But even in C11, `strcpy_s` is optional. All standard library implementations do not provide all optional features. So, the answer seems to be: Because none of the C standard libraries you have installed declare it.

> How to I get strcpy_s, strtok_s, and all the other safe string functions onto my system?

You will need to either find a library that implements them all, or implement them yourself.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer. How to I get strcpy_s, strtok_s, and all the other safe string functions onto my system?

Comment: @SodAlmighty why do you think so? In my opinion, this is quite helpful to anyone wondering why they don't have headers that define `strcpy_s`, which is what you asked. I've now answered your new question as well.

Comment: Ah. So, in order to find and get them, I have to find and get them. Right. THIS IS NOT HELPFUL!!! This is a NON-ANSWER. Why are people upvoting it?

Comment: @SodAlmighty Do you have an idea for how to improve the answer?

Comment: Yes. Telling me where to get the missing functions would be pretty useful.

Comment: @SodAlmighty are you sure that someone has implemented the missing functions? Have you tried investigating that?