# Strange symbols in dialog box

Tags: c++

I'm trying to have several store items display in a dialog box.

I'm trying to get the values from a txt file to line up with each segment (ID Number, Price, etc I'm not even sure if that's right), but when I run it, the dialog box shows completely different values for everything.

Here's the txt file (named **Store Sales.txt**)

> 0-8053-7442-6 Problem Solving with C++ 1 45.50
>
> 7751158146 Looney Tunes Diskettes 12 8.50
>
> 88869809780 HP Laser Printer Paper 3 10.99
>
> 2429412454 No. 2 Pencil 24 0.10
>
> 4895469286 Note Pad 5 0.89

And this is the code I've gotten so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

ifstream inFile;

class Product
{
private:
    char idNum[70];
    char Pname[100];
    double Price;
    int Quantity;
public:
    Product();
    Product(char[], char[], double, int);
    double getPrice();
    int getQuantity();
    void setProductCode(char[]);
    void setName(char[]);
    void setPrice(double);
    void setQuantity(int);
    int fulfillOrder(int);
    void print();
};

Product::Product()
{
    idNum[70] = '\0';
    Pname[100] = '\0';
}

Product::Product(char ID[], char PN[], double Pr, int Qu)
{
    setProductCode(ID);
    setName(PN);
    setPrice(Pr);
    setQuantity(Qu);
}

double Product::getPrice()
{
    cout << "Price: " << Price << endl;
    return Price;
}

int Product::getQuantity()
{
    cout << "Quantitiy: " << Quantity << endl;
    return Quantity;
}

void Product::setProductCode(char ID[])
{
    strcpy_s(idNum, ID);
}

void Product::setName(char PN[])
{
    strcpy_s(Pname, PN);
}

void Product::setPrice(double newPrice)
{
    if (newPrice >= 0)
    {
        Price = newPrice;
    }
    else
    {
        Price = 0;
    }
}

void Product::setQuantity(int newQuantity)
{
    if (newQuantity >= 0)
    {
        Quantity = newQuantity;
    }
    else
    {
        Quantity = 0;
    }
}

int Product::fulfillOrder(int orderq)
{
    if (orderq<0)
    {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        orderq = 0;
        cout << "Shipped: " << orderq << endl;
    }

    else if (orderq <= Quantity)
    {
        orderq = Quantity;
        Quantity -= orderq;
        cout << "Shipped: " << orderq << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        orderq = Quantity;
        orderq = 0;
        cout << "Shipped: " << orderq << endl;
    }
    return orderq;
}

void Product::print()
{
    do
    {
        Quantity * .1;
    } while (Quantity>10);

    cout << "Product ID: " << idNum << " Product Name: " << Pname << " Price: " << Price << " Quantity: " << Quantity << endl;
}

int main()
{
    inFile.open("C:\\Users\\Spectre\\Desktop\\C++ Work\\Store Sales.txt");

    Product product1 = Product();
    cout << "Product 1" << endl;
    product1.getPrice();
    product1.getQuantity();
    product1.print();

    Product product2 = Product();
    cout << "Product 2" << endl;
    product2.getPrice();
    product2.getQuantity();
    product2.print();

    Product product3 = Product();
    cout << "Product 3" << endl;
    product3.getPrice();
    product3.getQuantity();
    product3.print();

    Product product4 = Product();
    cout << "Product 4" << endl;
    product4.getPrice();
    product4.getQuantity();
    product4.print();

    Product product5 = Product();
    cout << "Product 5" << endl;
    product5.getPrice();
    product5.getQuantity();
    product5.print();

    {
        cout << "Unable to open the selected file. Please try again or choose another file.";
        //exit(0);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if it's because of the way the txt values are typed or if it's something with getting the values from the txt file.

Answer (score 1):

Your default `Product` constructor doesn't initialize `Quantity` or `Price` and it references invalid indexes in both `idNum` and `Pname`. All of this results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is

```
do
{
    Quantity * .1;
} while (Quantity>10);
```

Above expression is of no use and might be causing problem as the expression result is not used

Another problem is

```
void Product::setProductCode(char ID[])
{
    strcpy_s(idNum, ID);
}

void Product::setName(char PN[])
{
    strcpy_s(Pname, PN);
}
```

change it to

```
void Product::setProductCode(char ID[])
{
    strcpy(idNum, ID);
}

void Product::setName(char PN[])
{
    strcpy(Pname, PN);
}
```

After changing those I can see the output

```
Product 1
Price: 0
Quantitiy: 1606416072
Product ID:  Product Name:  Price: 0 Quantity: 1
Product 2
Price: 0
Quantitiy: 0
Product ID:  Product Name:  Price: 0 Quantity: 0
Product 3
Price: 0
Quantitiy: 0
Product ID:  Product Name:  Price: 0 Quantity: 0
Product 4
Price: 0
Quantitiy: 0
Product ID:  Product Name:  Price: 0 Quantity: 0
Product 5
Price: 0
Quantitiy: 0
Product ID:  Product Name:  Price: 0 Quantity: 0
Unable to open the selected file. Please try again or choose another file.sh: pause: command not found
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: When I did the strcpy change, it said that the strcpy was unsafe. I think I had the "_s" there to stop these errors. Is "_s" bad coding or something?

Comment: `strcpy_s` is a C function that is not guaranteed to exist in C++. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723946/why-does-strcpy-s-not-exist-anywhere-on-my-system). If it exists on your machine, then that's a compiler extension, but it's non-portable. (In fact, I tried to run your code, and those `strcpy_s` calls don't compile on g++ 5.4.0 for me)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017. Is there another way to do that segment and get the same results?